# SQL Server Float Datatype out of range

Tags: sql-server, precision, sqldatatypes

I have a query that I captured through an extended events session with a float datatype that looks like :

```
@variable = 120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If I try to run the same query in SSMS, I get the error:
*The number '120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' is out of the range for numeric representation (maximum precision 38).*

Same as if you were to run

```
DECLARE @variable float = 120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The query succeeded when the trace was running.  The Event is rpc_completed and it has a duration, cpu, rowcount, etc...

Not sure if this is relevant, but the query in question is an exec sp_executeSQL. The full query as captured by the trace looks like:

```
exec sp_executeSQL N'SELECT
    col1,
    col2
FROM table
WHERE col3 > @variable', N'@variable float', 
@variable = 120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So my question is, why is the code in the trace able to execute without error, but when I copy/paste that same code to SSMS it throws an error.  If I take that same code and trim off a bunch of those zeros it works.

I am running on SQL Azure DB.  I have reproduced on compatibility SQL2016, SQL2019, and on Prem SQL2019.

Comment: The literal `120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is first implicitly converted to decimal, hence the error.
Try `120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E0` (note E0 at the end)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024306/tsql-make-a-literal-float-value

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - done; cant resist an upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is the code in the trace able to execute without error, but when I
> copy/paste that same code to SSMS it throws an error.

When you put this query in SSMS

```
exec sp_executeSQL N'SELECT
    col1,
    col2
FROM table
WHERE col3 > @variable', N'@variable float', 
@variable = 120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

the literal `120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is interpreted as a numeric/decimal type. The engine tries to convert it to a value of numeric/decimal type and fails, because numeric has maximum precision of 38 digits.

If you put this query in SSMS, it should work

```
exec sp_executeSQL N'SELECT
    col1,
    col2
FROM table
WHERE col3 > @variable', N'@variable float', 
@variable = 120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E0
```

I've added `E0` at the end.

To make the `float` literal we need to use the scientific notation, as documented in [Constants (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

---

> why is the code in the trace able to execute without error

I can't say for sure, but I suspect that the code that you see in the trace is not exactly the same code that was sent to the SQL Server by the application. It could have been sent in such a way that the parameter type and value was actually `float`, not a text string with all these zeroes.

I think, the application is likely to make an RPC call passing proper parameter with proper type to the function call. So, there was never a conversion from a text string to `numeric` or `float` type when an application made this successful call.

Comment: RE "RPC call passing proper parameter with proper type" - I think so as well. It looks like a parameterised query. The only thing that confuses me are the trailing 0s in the number. Is it just a formatting oddity?

Comment: @Alex, it could easily be the odd way the trace presents/shows/formats its data. I don't have a lot of experience with extended events.

Comment: This put me on the right track.  I was taking the statement out the trace and executing that in C# just by putting the whole command into the Command.Text property.  I needed to execute as a stored procedure and declare the parameters explicitly.  I will add an answer below showing exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The string literal `120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is first implicitly converted to decimal, hence the error.

Try

```
DECLARE @variable float = 120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E0
```

Source: [TSQL - make a literal float value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024306/tsql-make-a-literal-float-value)

Answer (score 2):

Details on what I did to proof out the accepted answer above.

I was taking the trace statement and replaying it on another DB using C# like this (this will throw the out of range error):

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'SELECT @f',
    @params=N'@f float',@f=120700.800000000002910383045673370361328125";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What I need to do is extract those parts and build a stored procedure with parameters like this :

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_executesql";

SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter();
p1.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
p1.ParameterName = "@stmt";
p1.Value = "SELECT @f";

SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter();
p2.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
p2.ParameterName = "@params";
p2.Value = "@f float";

SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter();
p3.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Double;
p3.Value = 120700.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
p3.ParameterName = "@f";

cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I run that, it shows up in the trace as:

*exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'SELECT @f',@params=N'@f float',@f=120700.800000000002910383045673370361328125*

So the issue is that I cannot just take the statement from an rpc_completed event.  I need to parse it and reconstruct the stored procedure explicitly.

Comment: FYI: SQL Server Profiler allows you to replay events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/replay-a-trace-file-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Unfortunately, Profiler does not work with Azure SQL DB.